# Do-While Loop Not Working | TimeOut might be the problem HTML and JS

Tags: javascript, html, timeout, webgl

I am trying to create a growing/shrinking effect with WebGL.
I approached this problem by using setTimeout().
I incorporated a **do-while loop** so that this process can repeat

However, the growing/shrinking only occurs **once**.

My Code:

```js
document.getElementById("groNShrink").onclick = function()
  {
  var millisecondsToWait = 500;
  var max                = 3; // Max times
  do
    {
    balloonEffect++;
    for (var i = 0; i < max; i++)
      {
      setTimeout(function () 
        {
        changeRadius /= 1.15;
        }
        , millisecondsToWait * i);
      }
    setTimeout(function ()
      {
      for (var x = max; x !== 0; x--) 
        {
        setTimeout(function () 
          {
          changeRadius *= 1.15;
          }
          , millisecondsToWait * x);
        }
      }
      , millisecondsToWait * max);
    } 
  while (balloonEffect % 2 == 0);
  };
```

This is just my for my do-while loop.
I don't see where I went wrong maybe another pair of eyes will help.

Comment: Let me know if you need me to post my overall HTML & JS file

Comment: "balloonEffect % 2 == 0" is wrong condition. "balloonEffect % max !== 0"

Comment: what is the initial value of balloonEffect?